# Prove the identity $\Sigma_{d|n}\phi(d) = n$, where the sum is extended over all the divisors $d$ of $n$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

let $\phi$ denote the Euler's function.  Prove the identity $\Sigma_{d|n}\phi(d) = n$, where the sum is extended over all the divisors $d$ of $n$.

**attempt:** Suppose $Z$ is a cyclic group of order $n$. Then by theorem, every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. So every subgroup of Z is cyclic. And by another theorem, for each positive integer $q$ dividing $n$ , there is a unique subgroup of Z of order $q$, for each $d|n$.  Then each $q \in Z$ is contained in some cyclic subgroup. The number of elements of Z of order $d$ is $\phi(d)$ . Thus , in the cyclic group Z there are $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d|n$ . Since by Lagrange's theorem, every element has order that divides $n$ , then the number of elements in Z is  $\Sigma_{d|n}\phi(d) = n$.

Can someone please verify this? Any feedback would really help or better approach. Thank you!

Comment: Can this be solved using Iverson bracket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is a multiplicative function,
$$ F(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d) $$
is a multiplicative function, too (it can be regarded as a simple consequence of the Chinese remainder theorem). If we take $f=\phi$ and $n=p^k$, we have:
$$ \sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d) = \sum_{j=0}^{k}\phi(p^j) = 1+(p-1)\sum_{j=1}^{k}p^{j-1} = p^k, $$
hence for every $n$,
$$ \sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d) = n$$
holds.

Comment: That is a nice proof! Thank you. Does my proof make sense?

Comment: @Mahidevran: your proof is perfectly fine, I just provided an alternative.

Comment: This is correct? \begin{align} F(mn)&=\sum_{d\mid mn}f(d)\\
&=\sum_{d_1\mid m,d_2\mid n }f(d_1d_2)\\
&=\sum_{d_1\mid m,d_2\mid n }f(d_1)f(d_2)\\
&=\sum_{d_1\in m}\sum_{d_2\mid n }f(d_1)f(d_2)\\
&=\sum_{d_1\in m}f(d_1)\sum_{d_2\mid n }f(d_2)\\
&=F(m)F(n).
\end{align}