# Why the number of elements of $ Z$ of order $d$ is $\varphi (d)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, cyclic-groups

I was trying to understand this problem solution:

Let $\varphi$ denote Euler's $\phi$-function. Prove the identity $\sum_{d|n} \phi(d) = n,$ where the sum is extended over all the divisors $d$ of $n.$

The solution is given here:

[Prove the identity $\Sigma_{d|n}\phi(d) = n$, where the sum is extended over all the divisors $d$ of $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525998/prove-the-identity-sigma-dn-phid-n-where-the-sum-is-extended-over-all)

I am wondering why the following statement in the solution is true: "the number of elements of $ Z$ of order $d$ is $\varphi (d)$" is not the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/12Z)^\times$ is a counterexample to it as it has 3 ( 5, 7,11) elements of order 2 while $\varphi (2)$ is just 1?

Comment: The multiplicative group $(\Bbb Z / 12 \Bbb Z)^{\times}$ is not cyclic.  Try the additive group.

Comment: So this statement is only true for additive groups? @RobertShore

Comment: Also, how do you know that it is not cyclic? @RobertShore

Comment: Because it's isomorphic to the Klein group.

Comment: How about my first comment? @RobertShore

Comment: Yes, the statement assumes a cyclic group of order $n$, which means the additive group.